# Fullpage Transitions with meteorJS, iron:router and famo.us

Tags: meteor, iron-router, famo.us

I´m playing with `meteor`, `iron router`  and `famo.us` (`mjn:famous` integration for meteor)and was wondering how is the common way to create full page transitions with famous surfaces without writing the same code again when I add more views. Does someone have an easy to understand code example for me to create simple transitions like fade from View A -> View B?
I also use `gadicohen:famous-views`.

I´m also confused which famous integration I should use. there is `mjn:famous` and `raix:famono` available for meteorJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RenderController accepts some reactive data. Lets say that we have something

```
{{#RenderController}}
  {{#if somethingTrue}}
     {{>template1}}
  {{else}}
     {{>template2}}
  {{/if}}
{{/RenderController}}
```

So when the `somethingTrue` changes reactively `RenderController` re-renders the page. Same thing comes to Iron router. Coz of Iron router `{{>yield}}` is reactive, pages are reactively changed with animations.

Very un-complete project.. but you can see codes & github 
[Famome](http://famome.meteor.com)

Comment: thx but for some reason raix:famono is not working for me. mjn:famous works instead.